# Eloquent filters and queries

Tags: laravel

I have a query like this:

```
$events = Appen::find(2)->events()->take(230)->get()->toArray();
```

How can I add filters, say.

```
If (Input::has('gege')
   //add some filter to the query above..
```

What I am basically asking, how can I split the query without it executing right away? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
$events = Appen::find(2)->events()->take(230);
if(Input::has('gege')) {
    $events->where(); //add filter here
}
$events->get()->toArray();
```

Doing get() and paginate() will execute the query.
Hope that helps! Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, you can put your logic inside a closure inside a where():

```
   $events = Appen::find(2)
   ->events()
   ->take(230)
   ->where(function($query){
       if (Input::has('gege')){
           $query->where(); //add filter query here
       }
   })
   ->get()->toArray();
```